# Create a function that is just an independent for loop?

Tags: javascript, function

In JavaScript, would it be wrong to create a function like:

```
//Loop to end
function loopToEnd(values, code){
  for(var i=0; i < values.length; i++){code};
}
```

Or would this be unreasonable?

Comment: No it is not unreasonable (if done right). In fact, ES5 adds the [`forEach` method to arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which is doing the same. In your case, `code` should be a function.

Comment: Depends whether `code` is a string or function. You  probably want `.forEach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unreasonable, although I'd have to assume that `code` is a function taking at the very least the object of iteration, and possibly an index. Most JS libraries have this, like jQuery's `each`. Its function takes the index and object of iteration; [see a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/X9nft/).